# Alternatives to using autocomplete in forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3c

So the autocomplete="off" attribute is invalid HTML according to the w3c. Are there valid ways to do this in HTML, CSS or JavaScript? Or do we just have to plan on some of our forms not validating because we want to use this functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`autocomplete` is valid [HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-autocomplete-attribute) and is supported by all major browsers. What more do you want?

Comment: HTML5 is still only proposed, so technically we still fail validation. But thanks for the heads up on HTML5 now including it. And as for the major browsers, Opera doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript:
element.setAttribute("autocomplete","off");

Comment: This is nothing but a hacky work-around to please the validator, since it comes down to exactly the same thing in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input.autocompleteOff").attr("autocomplete","off");
});
```

For all textbox -

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("input").attr("autocomplete","off");});
```